# Iterate over another url with a for loop in django

Tags: python, django, loops, django-views, python-requests

I'm setting up a button that save API datas into my database and I'm trying to find a way to get the description out of every products but they are not included with the main url that get all products by city: (`https://www.test-headout.com/api/public/v1/product/listing/list-by/city?cityCode=BARCELONA&limit=5000&language=fr`), they are only included if we use this link which call a product by its `id`: (`https://www.test-headout.com/api/public/v1/product/get/508`).

So I was adviced to first hit the Listing API to get all products. Iterate over the list and get `id` and hit the `product/get` API to get the description.

This is what I've tried so far but I don't get how to do the iteration part:

My Django views:

```
def api_data(request):
    response = requests.get("https://www.test-headout.com/api/public/v1/product/listing/list-by/city?cityCode=BARCELONA&limit=5000&language=fr",
      headers={
        "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_TEST_API_KEY
      }
    ).json()

    if (request.GET.get('mybtn')):
        for item in response['items']:  # for loop
            Product.objects.get_or_create(
                title=item['name'],
                destination=item['city']['name'],
                #description=response['contentListHtml'][0]['html'],
                link=item['canonicalUrl'],
                image=item['image']['url'],
            )

    return render(request, "form.html")
```

How can I do this?

Based on @ralf answer this is what I came out with
:

```
def api_data(request):
    if (request.GET.get('mybtn')):
        url_1 = requests.get("https://www.test-headout.com/api/public/v1/product/listing/list-by/city?cityCode=BARCELONA&limit=5000&language=fr",
          headers={
            "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_TEST_API_KEY
          }
        )

        base_url_2 = requests.get("https://www.test-headout.com/api/public/v1/product/get/",
          headers={
            "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_TEST_API_KEY
          }
        )

        resp_data = url_1.json()

        for item in resp_data['items']:
            url = '{}{}'.format(base_url_2, item['id'])
            resp_data = url.json()

            Product.objects.get_or_create(
                title=item['name'],
                destination=item['city']['name'],
                description=response['contentListHtml'][0]['html'],
                link=item['canonicalUrl'],
                image=item['image']['url']
            )

    return render(request, "form.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to add even more code to my other answer, so here goes a new one. So here is how your code should probably look, based on your updated question code:

```
def api_data(request):
    if request.GET.get('mybtn'):    # this should probably be compared to something ???
        resp_1 = requests.get(
            "https://www.test-headout.com/api/public/v1/product/listing/list-by/city?cityCode=BARCELONA&limit=5000&language=fr",
            headers={
                "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_TEST_API_KEY
            })
        resp_1_data = resp_1.json()
        base_url_2 = "https://www.test-headout.com/api/public/v1/product/get/"

        for item in resp_1_data['items']:
            # concat ID to the URL string
            url = '{}{}'.format(base_url_2, item['id'])

            # make the HTTP request
            resp_2 = requests.get(
                url,
                headers={
                    "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_TEST_API_KEY
                })
            resp_2_data = resp_2.json()

            Product.objects.get_or_create(
                title=item['name'],
                destination=item['city']['name'],
                description=resp_2_data['contentListHtml'][0]['html'],
                link=item['canonicalUrl'],
                image=item['image']['url']
            )

    return render(request, "form.html")
```

Comment: Also, the part `if request.GET.get('mybtn'):` should probably be improved. That condition as it is checks if the content of `'mybtn'` evaluates to `True`, which can be very misleading. Probably best to compare to a explicit string `if request.GET.get('mybtn') == 'something':`

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your help! And cool, didn't know that the if part could be improved, always appreciated to know that!! Best of luck in all your project!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to make a GET request for each item? This can be done inside the for-loop that you already have.

Maybe like this:

```
import requests

url_1 = 'https://www.test-headout.com/api/public/v1/product/listing/list-by/city?cityCode=BARCELONA&limit=5000&language=fr'
base_url_2 = 'https://www.test-headout.com/api/public/v1/product/get/'
resp_data = requests.get(url_1).json()

for item in resp_data['items']:
    url = '{}{}'.format(base_url_2, item['id'])
    resp_data = requests.get(url).json()

    print('item')
    print(item)
    print('resp_data')
    print(resp_data)

    break

    Product.objects.get_or_create(...)
```

Running the code for the first item (notice the `break` I put there for this test) I get the correct output:

```
item
{'id': '7324', 'name': 'Billets Accès Rapide pour la Sagrada Familia', 'url': '/tour/7324/spain/barcelona/fast-track-tickets-to-sagrada-familia', 'canonicalUrl': 'https://www.test-headout.com/tour/7324/spain/barcelona/fast-track-tickets-to-sagrada-familia', 'city': {'name': 'Barcelona', 'code': 'BARCELONA'}, 'image': {'url': '//cdn-imgix.headout.com/tour/13376/TOUR-IMAGE/eaeefed3-c87b-4531-82c0-0089dc8d11ec-7324-barcelona-sagrada-familia-skyline-day-01.jpg'}, 'neibhourhood': 'Barcelona', 'primaryCategory': {'id': 327, 'name': 'Sagrada Familia', 'cityCode': 'BARCELONA', 'url': '/category/327'}, 'currency': {'code': 'EUR', 'currencyName': 'Euro', 'symbol': 'EUR', 'localSymbol': '€', 'precision': 2, 'currency': 'EUR'}, 'startGeolocation': {'latitude': 41.403629302978516, 'longitude': 2.1743557453155518}, 'ratingCumulative': {'avg': 4.7, 'count': 2496}, 'pricing': {'type': 'PER_PERSON', 'currencyCode': 'EUR', 'minimumPrice': {'originalPrice': 17, 'finalPrice': 17}, 'bestDiscount': 0}}
resp_data
{'id': 7324, 'name': 'Fast Track Tickets to Sagrada Familia', 'url': '/tour/7324/spain/barcelona/fast-track-tickets-to-sagrada-familia', 'canonicalUrl': 'https://www.test-headout.com/tour/7324/spain/barcelona/fast-track-tickets-to-sagrada-familia', 'neighbourhood': 'La Sagrada Familia', 'city': {'name': 'Barcelona', 'code': 'BARCELONA'}, 'currency': {'code': 'EUR', 'name': 'Euro', 'symbol': 'EUR', 'localSymbol': '€', 'precision': 2}, 'displayTags': ['family friendly', 'sightseeing tours', 'day trips', 'attraction tickets', 'skip the line', 'city passes'], 'images': [{'url': '//cdn-imgix.headout.com/tour/13376/TOUR-IMAGE/eaeefed3-c87b-4531-82c0-0089dc8d11ec-7324-barcelona-sagrada-familia-skyline-day-01.jpg'}, {'url': '//cdn-imgix.headout.com/tour/13376/TOUR-IMAGE/ee6912c4-1f4a-482b-be4e-5c035404da96-7324-barcelona-sagrada-familia-skyline-day-02.jpg'}, {'url': '//cdn-imgix.headout.com/tour/13376/TOUR-IMAGE/d983bcd2-be68-4e0e-9066-82adb95f468c-7324-barcelona-sagrada-familia-skyline-day-03.jpg'}, {'url': '//cdn-imgix.headout.com/tour/13376/TOUR-IMAGE/e8afec3d-acad-4056-b15c-f63f8fda9a22-7324-barcelona-sagrada-familia-skyline-day-04.jpg'}], 'contentListHtml': [{'title': 'Summary', 'type': 'SUMMARY_HTML', 'html': '<h2>What to Expect</h2>\n<p>Purchasing tickets for entry at the venue is not only time consuming but often times, futile. Since each time slot for entry into the basilica has limited capacity, same day entry tickets on site tend to sell out before mid-day, even if you waited in line for several hours, as many visitors must do. Our fast track Sagrada Familia tickets provide you with priority access to this iconic basilica. Once you book your tickets, you will receive them via email which you can then display on your phone to skip the ticketing line entirely and proceed directly to the security check.</p>\n<p>Before you head into the inner sanctum of the church, make sure to explore the outer walls and facades of the Sagrada Familia. Two of the three facades, Nativity, and Passion, have been completed, while the third, the Glory Facade, is still under construction. The Nativity facade tells the story of the birth of Jesus Christ while the Passion Facade is dedicated to his death. Though you can admire the facades and towers from the outside, these tickets do not give you access to the towers themselves. If you wish to gain entry to the towers along with the Basilica, please click <a href="https://www.headout.com/tour/7603/spain/barcelona/sagrada-familia-skip-the-line-tickets-with-tower-access-and-audio-guide">here.</a></p>\n<p>As you move inside, you will come face to face with one of the most enchanting interiors of any church in the world. The vaults of the Basilica are as high as 70 meters in certain places and the beautiful, stained glass windows, constructed as per Gaudi’s plans, as well as the pillars holding up the ceiling,  make the entire space appear as though it were the hollowed out rib cage of some giant celestial beast. The magical natural light filtering through the basilica’s exquisite windows will take your breath away and transport you to a different time.</p>'}, {'title': 'Highlights', 'type': 'HIGHLIGHTS_HTML', 'html': '<ul>\n<li>Get a chance to visit the most iconic monument in Barcelona that has been under construction since 1882, this UNESCO World Heritage Site attracts more visitors each year than any other landmark in Spain.</li>\n<li>With these fast-track tickets that you can book online, you need not worry about the long winding queues and you will also be guaranteed access to an otherwise sold out attraction. </li>\n<li>Marvel at the magnificent inner sanctums of the basilica with its extraordinary vaulted ceilings and stained glass windows, bound to sweep you off your feet.</li>\n</ul>'}, {'title': 'FAQs', 'type': 'FAQ_HTML', 'html': '<h2>Know Before You Go</h2>\n<p><strong>Important Information</strong></p>\n<p>Groups with more than a total of 9 people, either adults or children, will not be allowed to gain entry into the Basilica. Should you wish to visit with a group of more than 9 people, you must book a guided visit as per the rules of the Basilica. You can book this by clicking <a href="https://www.headout.com/tour/3441/spain/barcelona/fast-track-guided-tour-of-sagrada-familia-without-tower-access">here.</a></p>\n<p><strong>Timings</strong></p>\n<p>Entry to the Sagrada Familia is timed. You will have the option to choose the time slot for your entry during the next step of your booking. Please note that you will <strong><em>only be allowed to gain entry at the time chosen during the booking</em></strong> so we recommend arriving 15 minutes in advance in order to ensure a hassle-free entry. Though your entry is timed, you may explore the basilica for as long as you wish. Most visitors spend around an hour and a half inside. </p>\n<p>November to February - 9:00 AM to 6:00 PM<br>\nMarch - 9:00 AM to 7:00 PM<br>\nApril to September - 9:00 AM to 8:00 PM<br>\nOctober - 9:00 AM to 7:00 PM<br>\nDecember 25, 26, January 1 and 6 - 9:00 AM to 2:00 PM<br></p>\n<p><strong>Reduced Price Tickets</strong></p>\n<p>Entry for children aged eleven and below is free, however, they will not receive an audioguide. You will have the option to choose the number of children who require free entry at the time of checkout.</p>\n<p><strong>Getting There</strong></p>\n<p>To get to the Sagrada Familia, you can take any of the following options:<br>\nBy Metro: Line 2 and Line 5 to the Sagrada Familia Station.<br>\nBy Bus: Buses 19, 33, 34, 43, 44, 50, 51, B20 and B24 will stop at the Sagrada Familia.<br></p>\n<p>The main access to the Sagrada Familia is on the Carrer de la Marina (C/Marina).</p>\n<p><strong>Dress Code</strong></p>\n<p>To pay your respects to the Holy family, you must be appropriately covered to enter this sacred monument. No tank tops, strapless shirts, short shorts or sandals will be accepted. You will be denied entry if this dress code is not adhered to.</p>\n<p><strong>Accessibility</strong></p>\n<p>The insides of the Sagrada Familia is wheelchair accessible. \nHowever, due to the narrow stairways leading to the towers, tower access is not suitable for individuals with mobility impairments.</p>\n<p>Only small backpacks and regular-size handbags are allowed inside. Guests with larger bags will not be allowed to enter (as there are no storage facilities).</p>'}, {'title': 'Cancellation Policy', 'type': 'CANCELLATION_HTML', 'html': '<h2>Strict Cancellation Policy</h2>\n<p>These tickets cannot be cancelled, amended or rescheduled.</p>'}, {'title': 'Ticket Delivery Information', 'type': 'TICKET_DELIVERY_INFO_HTML', 'html': '<p>You will receive an email confirmation with your Sagrada Familia mobile tickets instantly. No need to print. You can skip the ticket line and go directly to the security line with your mobile ticket.</p>'}, {'title': 'Inclusions', 'type': 'INCLUSIONS_HTML', 'html': '<ul>\n<li>Skip-the-Line access to the Sagrada Familia.</li>\n</ul>'}, {'title': 'Exclusions', 'type': 'EXCLUSIONS_HTML', 'html': '<ul>\n<li>Tower access.</li>\n</ul>'}], 'content': [{'title': 'Summary', 'type': 'SUMMARY_HTML', 'html': '<h2>What to Expect</h2>\n<p>Purchasing tickets for entry at the venue is not only time consuming but often times, futile. Since each time slot for entry into the basilica has limited capacity, same day entry tickets on site tend to sell out before mid-day, even if you waited in line for several hours, as many visitors must do. Our fast track Sagrada Familia tickets provide you with priority access to this iconic basilica. Once you book your tickets, you will receive them via email which you can then display on your phone to skip the ticketing line entirely and proceed directly to the security check.</p>\n<p>Before you head into the inner sanctum of the church, make sure to explore the outer walls and facades of the Sagrada Familia. Two of the three facades, Nativity, and Passion, have been completed, while the third, the Glory Facade, is still under construction. The Nativity facade tells the story of the birth of Jesus Christ while the Passion Facade is dedicated to his death. Though you can admire the facades and towers from the outside, these tickets do not give you access to the towers themselves. If you wish to gain entry to the towers along with the Basilica, please click <a href="https://www.headout.com/tour/7603/spain/barcelona/sagrada-familia-skip-the-line-tickets-with-tower-access-and-audio-guide">here.</a></p>\n<p>As you move inside, you will come face to face with one of the most enchanting interiors of any church in the world. The vaults of the Basilica are as high as 70 meters in certain places and the beautiful, stained glass windows, constructed as per Gaudi’s plans, as well as the pillars holding up the ceiling,  make the entire space appear as though it were the hollowed out rib cage of some giant celestial beast. The magical natural light filtering through the basilica’s exquisite windows will take your breath away and transport you to a different time.</p>'}, {'title': 'Highlights', 'type': 'HIGHLIGHTS_HTML', 'html': '<ul>\n<li>Get a chance to visit the most iconic monument in Barcelona that has been under construction since 1882, this UNESCO World Heritage Site attracts more visitors each year than any other landmark in Spain.</li>\n<li>With these fast-track tickets that you can book online, you need not worry about the long winding queues and you will also be guaranteed access to an otherwise sold out attraction. </li>\n<li>Marvel at the magnificent inner sanctums of the basilica with its extraordinary vaulted ceilings and stained glass windows, bound to sweep you off your feet.</li>\n</ul>'}, {'title': 'FAQs', 'type': 'FAQ_HTML', 'html': '<h2>Know Before You Go</h2>\n<p><strong>Important Information</strong></p>\n<p>Groups with more than a total of 9 people, either adults or children, will not be allowed to gain entry into the Basilica. Should you wish to visit with a group of more than 9 people, you must book a guided visit as per the rules of the Basilica. You can book this by clicking <a href="https://www.headout.com/tour/3441/spain/barcelona/fast-track-guided-tour-of-sagrada-familia-without-tower-access">here.</a></p>\n<p><strong>Timings</strong></p>\n<p>Entry to the Sagrada Familia is timed. You will have the option to choose the time slot for your entry during the next step of your booking. Please note that you will <strong><em>only be allowed to gain entry at the time chosen during the booking</em></strong> so we recommend arriving 15 minutes in advance in order to ensure a hassle-free entry. Though your entry is timed, you may explore the basilica for as long as you wish. Most visitors spend around an hour and a half inside. </p>\n<p>November to February - 9:00 AM to 6:00 PM<br>\nMarch - 9:00 AM to 7:00 PM<br>\nApril to September - 9:00 AM to 8:00 PM<br>\nOctober - 9:00 AM to 7:00 PM<br>\nDecember 25, 26, January 1 and 6 - 9:00 AM to 2:00 PM<br></p>\n<p><strong>Reduced Price Tickets</strong></p>\n<p>Entry for children aged eleven and below is free, however, they will not receive an audioguide. You will have the option to choose the number of children who require free entry at the time of checkout.</p>\n<p><strong>Getting There</strong></p>\n<p>To get to the Sagrada Familia, you can take any of the following options:<br>\nBy Metro: Line 2 and Line 5 to the Sagrada Familia Station.<br>\nBy Bus: Buses 19, 33, 34, 43, 44, 50, 51, B20 and B24 will stop at the Sagrada Familia.<br></p>\n<p>The main access to the Sagrada Familia is on the Carrer de la Marina (C/Marina).</p>\n<p><strong>Dress Code</strong></p>\n<p>To pay your respects to the Holy family, you must be appropriately covered to enter this sacred monument. No tank tops, strapless shirts, short shorts or sandals will be accepted. You will be denied entry if this dress code is not adhered to.</p>\n<p><strong>Accessibility</strong></p>\n<p>The insides of the Sagrada Familia is wheelchair accessible. \nHowever, due to the narrow stairways leading to the towers, tower access is not suitable for individuals with mobility impairments.</p>\n<p>Only small backpacks and regular-size handbags are allowed inside. Guests with larger bags will not be allowed to enter (as there are no storage facilities).</p>'}, {'title': 'Cancellation Policy', 'type': 'CANCELLATION_HTML', 'html': '<h2>Strict Cancellation Policy</h2>\n<p>These tickets cannot be cancelled, amended or rescheduled.</p>'}, {'title': 'Ticket Delivery Information', 'type': 'TICKET_DELIVERY_INFO_HTML', 'html': '<p>You will receive an email confirmation with your Sagrada Familia mobile tickets instantly. No need to print. You can skip the ticket line and go directly to the security line with your mobile ticket.</p>'}, {'title': 'Inclusions', 'type': 'INCLUSIONS_HTML', 'html': '<ul>\n<li>Skip-the-Line access to the Sagrada Familia.</li>\n</ul>'}, {'title': 'Exclusions', 'type': 'EXCLUSIONS_HTML', 'html': '<ul>\n<li>Tower access.</li>\n</ul>'}], 'startLocation': {'geolocation': {'latitude': 41.403629302978516, 'longitude': 2.1743557453155518}, 'address': {'addressLine1': 'Sagrada Família, Carrer de la marina', 'addressLine2': None, 'cityName': 'Barcelona', 'postalCode': '08013', 'state': 'Catalunya', 'countryName': 'Spain'}}, 'endLocation': {'geolocation': {'latitude': 41.403629302978516, 'longitude': 2.1743557453155518}, 'address': {'addressLine1': 'Sagrada Família, Carrer de la marina', 'addressLine2': None, 'cityName': 'Barcelona', 'postalCode': '08013', 'state': 'Catalunya', 'countryName': 'Spain'}}, 'productType': 'ATTRACTION', 'ratingCumulative': {'avg': 4.7, 'count': 2496}, 'hasInstantConfirmation': True, 'hasMobileTicket': True, 'variants': [{'id': 13376, 'name': 'Fast Track', 'description': '- Get Fast Track Access that lets you bypass the ticket line & directly join the security line\r\n- Get guaranteed timed entry to the basilica\r\n- Mobile vouchers for convenient access', 'duration': 5400000, 'inventoryType': 'FIXED_START_FLEXIBLE_DURATION', 'pax': {'min': 1, 'max': 9}, 'cashback': {'value': 10.0, 'type': 'PERCENTAGE'}, 'ticketDeliveryInfoHtml': '<p>You will receive an email confirmation with your Sagrada Familia mobile tickets within 30 minutes of your purchase. No need to print. You can skip the ticket line and go directly to the security line with your mobile ticket.</p>\n<p>Please note that, in some rare cases, if the requested time slot is unavailable, we will book the next available time slot within 30 minutes of your preferred entry time. Please check the exact entry time on your tickets once you receive them.</p>', 'inputFields': [{'oldId': 42249, 'id': 'NAME', 'name': 'Full Name', 'dataType': 'STRING', 'validation': {'regex': '\\s*[^\\s]+\\s+[^\\s]+.*', 'minLength': 3, 'maxLength': 80, 'minValue': None, 'maxValue': None, 'required': True, 'values': None}, 'level': 'PRIMARY_CUSTOMER'}, {'oldId': 42250, 'id': 'EMAIL', 'name': 'Email', 'dataType': 'STRING', 'validation': {'regex': "(?i)^((([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+(\\.([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+)*)|((\\x22)((((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(\\\\([\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))))*(((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(\\x22)))@((([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.)+(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))+(\\s*,\\s*((([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+(\\.([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+)*)|((\\x22)((((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(\\\\([\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))))*(((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(\\x22)))@((([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.)+(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))+)*$", 'minLength': 5, 'maxLength': None, 'minValue': None, 'maxValue': None, 'required': True, 'values': None}, 'level': 'PRIMARY_CUSTOMER'}, {'oldId': 42251, 'id': 'PHONE', 'name': 'Phone', 'dataType': 'STRING', 'validation': {'regex': None, 'minLength': None, 'maxLength': 40, 'minValue': None, 'maxValue': None, 'required': True, 'values': None}, 'level': 'PRIMARY_CUSTOMER'}]}, {'id': 13377, 'name': 'Fast Track + Audioguide', 'description': '- Audioguide (Spanish, Catalan, Chinese, English, French, German, Italian, Japanese, Portuguese, Russian)\r\n- Get Fast Track Access that lets you bypass the ticket line & directly join the security line\r\n- Get guaranteed timed entry to the basilica\r\n- Mobile vouchers for convenient access', 'duration': 5400000, 'inventoryType': 'FIXED_START_FLEXIBLE_DURATION', 'pax': {'min': 1, 'max': 9}, 'cashback': {'value': 10.0, 'type': 'PERCENTAGE'}, 'ticketDeliveryInfoHtml': '<p>You will receive an email confirmation with your Sagrada Familia mobile tickets within 30 minutes of your purchase. No need to print. You can skip the ticket line and go directly to the security line with your mobile ticket.</p>\n<p>Please note that, in some rare cases, if the requested time slot is unavailable, we will book the next available time slot within 30 minutes of your preferred entry time. Please check the exact entry time on your tickets once you receive them.</p>', 'inputFields': [{'oldId': 42252, 'id': 'NAME', 'name': 'Full Name', 'dataType': 'STRING', 'validation': {'regex': '\\s*[^\\s]+\\s+[^\\s]+.*', 'minLength': 3, 'maxLength': 80, 'minValue': None, 'maxValue': None, 'required': True, 'values': None}, 'level': 'PRIMARY_CUSTOMER'}, {'oldId': 42253, 'id': 'EMAIL', 'name': 'Email', 'dataType': 'STRING', 'validation': {'regex': "(?i)^((([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+(\\.([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+)*)|((\\x22)((((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(\\\\([\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))))*(((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(\\x22)))@((([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.)+(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))+(\\s*,\\s*((([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+(\\.([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+)*)|((\\x22)((((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(\\\\([\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))))*(((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(\\x22)))@((([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.)+(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))+)*$", 'minLength': 5, 'maxLength': None, 'minValue': None, 'maxValue': None, 'required': True, 'values': None}, 'level': 'PRIMARY_CUSTOMER'}, {'oldId': 42254, 'id': 'PHONE', 'name': 'Phone', 'dataType': 'STRING', 'validation': {'regex': None, 'minLength': None, 'maxLength': 40, 'minValue': None, 'maxValue': None, 'required': True, 'values': None}, 'level': 'PRIMARY_CUSTOMER'}, {'oldId': 51544, 'id': 'CUSTOM_51544', 'name': 'Select Audioguide language', 'dataType': 'ENUM', 'validation': {'regex': None, 'minLength': None, 'maxLength': None, 'minValue': None, 'maxValue': None, 'required': True, 'values': ['English', 'Spanish', 'Catalan', 'Chinese', 'French', 'German', 'Italian', 'Japanese', 'Russian', 'Portuguese']}, 'level': 'PRIMARY_CUSTOMER'}]}, {'id': 18620, 'name': 'English Guided Tour', 'description': '- Get Fast Track Access to Sagrada Familia Basilica\r\n- Expert English Guide\r\n- Small group tour\r\n- Headphones', 'duration': 3600000, 'inventoryType': 'FIXED_START_FIXED_DURATION', 'pax': {'min': 1, 'max': 100}, 'cashback': {'value': 0.0, 'type': 'PERCENTAGE'}, 'ticketDeliveryInfoHtml': '', 'inputFields': [{'oldId': 58972, 'id': 'NAME', 'name': 'Full Name', 'dataType': 'STRING', 'validation': {'regex': '\\s*[^\\s]+\\s+[^\\s]+.*', 'minLength': 3, 'maxLength': 80, 'minValue': None, 'maxValue': None, 'required': True, 'values': None}, 'level': 'PRIMARY_CUSTOMER'}, {'oldId': 58973, 'id': 'EMAIL', 'name': 'Email', 'dataType': 'STRING', 'validation': {'regex': "(?i)^((([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+(\\.([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+)*)|((\\x22)((((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(\\\\([\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))))*(((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(\\x22)))@((([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.)+(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))+(\\s*,\\s*((([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+(\\.([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+)*)|((\\x22)((((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(\\\\([\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))))*(((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(\\x22)))@((([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.)+(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))+)*$", 'minLength': 5, 'maxLength': None, 'minValue': None, 'maxValue': None, 'required': True, 'values': None}, 'level': 'PRIMARY_CUSTOMER'}, {'oldId': 58974, 'id': 'PHONE', 'name': 'Phone', 'dataType': 'STRING', 'validation': {'regex': None, 'minLength': None, 'maxLength': 40, 'minValue': None, 'maxValue': None, 'required': True, 'values': None}, 'level': 'PRIMARY_CUSTOMER'}]}], 'pricing': {'type': 'PER_PERSON', 'currencyCode': 'EUR', 'minimumPrice': {'originalPrice': 17, 'finalPrice': 17}, 'bestDiscount': 0}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure to understand what you mean. Could you visit the urls, you don't need the api key to do so.

Comment: @locq I edited my answer. Yes, I can get the data correctly. Now it is up to you to parse the response and extract the description that you need.

Comment: I just edited the question to include what I came out with, but I'm not sure if what I put inside of the `Product.objects.get_or_create` is the right way, could you take a look?

Comment: @locq the call to `base_url_2 = requests.get()` has to go inside the loop; you have to make the call for each item, just like I showed in my answer.

Comment: I might need to work on my python knowledge because I'm very unsure of what you mean..